# how to check favorite item document is exist from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need when user open the meal page see if that meal in favorite or not by making the favorite icon color to red but i can't check if the meal document is in firestore or not.

I've tried to put this code in init state but it doesn't work i check icon color from isFavorite boolean.

```
    firestore
    .collection('favorites')
    .where('mealId', isEqualTo: widget.mealId)
    .where('userId', isEqualTo: userID)
    .getDocuments().then((f) {
  if(f.documents.isNotEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      isFavorite = true;
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      isFavorite = false;
    });
  }
});
```

this code make all of meals have a red favorite icon.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556990/how-to-check-for-an-empty-document-on-firestore

Comment: thanks for reply,, there is no code for that in dart ?

Comment: What doesn't work about your code? Does it reach `if(f.documents.isNotEmpty) {`? Is there an error?

Comment: it's not what i want i need to check a specific meal document and know if it exist make favorite icon red if not make boolean false.

Comment: Use limit(1) and check f.doucuments[0].exists