# How to solve problem favorite button after stored data on firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My problem has similar topic like this question [how to check favorite item document is exist from firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736122/how-to-check-favorite-item-document-is-exist-from-firestore) but at my case is on firebase realtime database on Java. I added a feature to add favorites to the Firebase database but the problem is only in the replacement of the favorite button on the Toolbar. The detail activity page like these picture on the below

[image]

When I clicked an item on list recyclerview, the detail activity must know the data has stored on node favorite and or not. When I clicked favorite button on toolbar of detailActivity, the data has successfull stored but when I open the item which has stored on favorit again, the color of favorite button not changed eventhough it has stored on favorite node.

[image]

This is code I've tried for the detail activity.

DetailEducationActivity.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2019 RONINGRUM. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.ui.detailactivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Objects;

import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.R;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.handler.GPSHandler;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.handler.HaversineHandler;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.model.TourismItem;

public class DetailEducatioActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    public static final String EXTRA_WISATA_KEY = "edukasi_key";
    private static final String MAP_VIEW_KEY = "mapViewBundle";

    private final static String TAG = "Pesan";
    private GoogleMap educationGoogleMap;
    private MapView educationMapView;

    private DatabaseReference educationDetailRef;

    private GPSHandler gpsHandler;
    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

    private TextView tvNameEducationDetail, tvAddressEducationDetail,
            tvDescEducation, tvDistanceEducation;

    private ImageView imgEducation;
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;

    private double startLat;
    private double startlng;
    private double endlat;
    private double endLng;
    private double distance;

    boolean isFavorite;
    TourismItem tourismItem = new TourismItem();
    String eduKey;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_education_category);
        tvNameEducationDetail = findViewById(R.id.name_place_education_detail);
        tvAddressEducationDetail = findViewById(R.id.address_place_education_detail);
        tvDescEducation = findViewById(R.id.info_place_education_detail);
        tvDistanceEducation = findViewById(R.id.distance_place_education_detail);
        imgEducation = findViewById(R.id.img_nature_education_detail);
        educationMapView = findViewById(R.id.loc_edu_map);
        collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapseToolbar);

        Toolbar toolbarEducation = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_education_detail);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarEducation);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_24dp);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_KEY);
        }
        educationMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        educationMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        eduKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_WISATA_KEY);
        if (eduKey == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass Extra");
        }
        educationDetailRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tourism").child(eduKey);
        Query eduQuery = educationDetailRef.orderByChild("category_tourism").equalTo("edukasi");
        gpsHandler = new GPSHandler(this);


        LoadEducationDetail();

    }

    private void LoadEducationDetail() {
        if (gpsHandler.isCanGetLocation()) {
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    tourismItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(TourismItem.class);
                    startLat = gpsHandler.getLatitude();
                    startlng = gpsHandler.getLongitude();
                    assert tourismItem != null;
                    endlat = tourismItem.getLat_location_tourism();
                    endLng = tourismItem.getLng_location_tourism();
                    distance = HaversineHandler.calculateDistance(startLat, startlng, endlat, endLng);

                    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String distanceFormat = String.format("%.2f", distance);
                    tvDistanceEducation.setText("" + distanceFormat + " km");
                    tvNameEducationDetail.setText(tourismItem.getName_tourism());
                    tvAddressEducationDetail.setText(tourismItem.getLocation_tourism());
                    tvDescEducation.setText(tourismItem.getInfo_tourism());
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(tourismItem.getUrl_photo()).into(imgEducation);
                    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
                    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.BaseOnOffsetChangedListener() {
                        boolean isShow = true;
                        int scrollRange = -1;

                        @Override
                        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                            }
                            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                                collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(tourismItem.getName_tourism());
                                isShow = true;
                            } else {
                                collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");
                                isShow = false;
                            }

                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Firebase Database Error" + databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            };
            educationDetailRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
            valueEventListener = eventListener;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }
        educationMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        educationGoogleMap = googleMap;
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tourismItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(TourismItem.class);
                assert tourismItem != null;
                double lattitude = tourismItem.getLat_location_tourism();
                double longitude = tourismItem.getLng_location_tourism();

                LatLng location = new LatLng(lattitude, longitude);
                educationGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location));
                educationGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 16.0f));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Firebase Database Error" + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        };
        educationDetailRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
        valueEventListener = eventListener;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        educationMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LoadEducationDetail();
        educationMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        educationMapView.onStop();
        educationDetailRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        educationMapView.onPause();
    }

//the button of favorite 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.favorite_menu, menu);

        MenuItem favorite = menu.findItem(R.id.add_to_favorite);
        if (isFavorite) {
            favorite.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmarkadded_24dp);
//            isFavorite = false;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_to_favorite) {
//this code when the button favorite click
            final String uid = user.getUid();
            final DatabaseReference favoritedb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Favorite");

            favoritedb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (uid.equals(dataSnapshot.child(uid).getKey())) {
                        if(isFavorite){
                            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_unbookmarked_24dp);
                            favoritedb.getRef().child(uid).child(eduKey).removeValue();
                            isFavorite = false;
                        }
                        else{
                            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmarkadded_24dp);
                            favoritedb.getRef().child(uid).child(eduKey).setValue(true);
                            isFavorite = true;
                        }


                    } else {
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmarkadded_24dp);
                        favoritedb.getRef().child(uid).child(eduKey).setValue(true);
                        isFavorite = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

and the list activity

EducationCategoryActivity.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2019 RONINGRUM. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.ui.categoryactivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.R;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.handler.GPSHandler;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.handler.NetworkHelper;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.handler.PermissionHandler;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.model.TourismItem;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.ui.detailactivity.DetailEducatioActivity;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.ui.mapsactivity.EducationCategoryMaps;
import co.id.roningrum.dolanapptugasakhir.viewholder.categoryviewholder.EducationViewHolder;

public class EducationCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rvEducationList;
    private ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TourismItem, EducationViewHolder> educationFirebaseAdapter;

    private GPSHandler gpsHandler;
    private PermissionHandler permissionHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_education);
        rvEducationList = findViewById(R.id.tourism_education_list);
        Toolbar toolbarEducation = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top_education);
        shimmerFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
        rvEducationList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ArrayList<TourismItem> tourismItems = new ArrayList<>();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarEducation);
        checkConnection();
    }

    private void checkConnection() {
        if (NetworkHelper.isConnectedToNetwork(getApplicationContext())) {
            showData();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Check your connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void showData() {
        if (havePermission()) {
            DatabaseReference educationCategoryDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query educationQuery = educationCategoryDB.child("Tourism").orderByChild("category_tourism").equalTo("edukasi");
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TourismItem> educationOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TourismItem>()
                    .setQuery(educationQuery, TourismItem.class)
                    .build();
            educationFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TourismItem, EducationViewHolder>(educationOptions) {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public EducationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                    return new EducationViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_education_category_menu, viewGroup, false));
                }

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EducationViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull TourismItem model) {
                    final DatabaseReference educationCategoryRef = getRef(position);
                    final String eductaionKey = educationCategoryRef.getKey();
                    Log.d("Check eduKey", ""+eductaionKey);

                    gpsHandler = new GPSHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    if (gpsHandler.isCanGetLocation()) {
                        double latitude = gpsHandler.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gpsHandler.getLongitude();

                        Log.i("Message", "CurLoc :" + latitude + "," + longitude);

                        shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                        shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        holder.showEducationTourismData(model, latitude, longitude);
                        holder.setOnClickListener(new EducationViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailEducatioActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(DetailEducatioActivity.EXTRA_WISATA_KEY, eductaionKey);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        gpsHandler.stopUsingGPS();
                        gpsHandler.showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                }

//                @NonNull
//                @Override
//                public ShoppingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
//                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_menu_shopping_category_tourism, viewGroup, false);
//                    return new ShoppingViewHolder(view);
//                }
            };
            educationFirebaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            rvEducationList.setAdapter(educationFirebaseAdapter);
        }
    }

    private boolean havePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            permissionHandler = PermissionHandler.getInstance(this);
            if (permissionHandler.isAllPermissionAvailable()) {
                Log.d("Pesan", "Permissions have done");
            } else {
                permissionHandler.setActivity(this);
                permissionHandler.deniedPermission();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Check your permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        for (int i : grantResults) {
            if (i == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("test", "Permission" + Arrays.toString(permissions) + "Success");
            } else {
                //denied
                permissionHandler.deniedPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                permissionHandler.deniedPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.petaMenu) {
            startActivity(new Intent(EducationCategoryActivity.this, EducationCategoryMaps.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
        if (educationFirebaseAdapter != null) {
            educationFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
        if (educationFirebaseAdapter != null) {
            educationFirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (educationFirebaseAdapter != null) {
            educationFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (educationFirebaseAdapter != null) {
            educationFirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the state of condition when the data has stored on favorite. I've tried to add code `datasnapshot.exist` but it can't change the color of favorite button. Thank you