# Android Firestore id of empty document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How i can get id of empty document (document without field but contains collections)

for Example

```
public void getUsersLists(OnSuccessListener<List<String>> callback) {

    storeCollection().get(getSource()).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            QuerySnapshot result = task.getResult();
            List<String> stringList = parseResult(result);
            callback.onSuccess(stringList);

        } else {
            callback.onError(task.getException());
        }

    }).addOnFailureListener(callback::onError);
}

private List<String> parseResult(QuerySnapshot result) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if (result != null) {

        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : result.getDocuments()) { <<----documetns is zero
            String name = snapshot.getId();

            list.add(name);
        }

    }

    return list;
}

private CollectionReference storeCollection() {
    return firestore()
            .collection(COLLECTION_DATA)
            .document(AuthManager.getUserId())
            .collection(COLLECTION_STORES);
}
```

[image]

`COLLECTION_STORES` contain empty document that contain other collections.
But i need to get the name/id of document, `collection.getDocuments()` return empty list, only after i add field via `Firebase console` the `collection.getDocuments()` returns the documents.

Is there a way to get the document name/id? or i must attach a field/object to document in this case?

I am understand that attaching object to this document can solve the issue, but it is also complicates the design.

Comment: If your collection holds multiple document then you need to filter that document.

Comment: the collection returns 0 documents because the document not contains fields (but the documents exist and i see them in console), so what can i filter?

Comment: Can you post full code what have tried ?

Comment: @Ashish added more code

Comment: @PavelPoley you can use the same solution mentioned in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556990/how-to-check-for-an-empty-document-on-firestore, as the task's result give us DocumentSnapshot  and can give us its size plus document details. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @AmninderSingh no DocumentSnapshot because the `result.getDocuments()` is empty

Comment: @PavelPoley try to use `QueryDocumentSnapshot` instead of `QuerySnapshot ` and you will easily  check its `existence` , `size` and `metadata ` . This is the  documentation for this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot

Comment: @AmninderSingh yes, already tried,`task.getResult()` size is 0, seems like it don't want to work without fields

Comment: @PavelPoley, it usually works without fields , somethings is missing in your query please check your values you passed in the query

Comment: @AmninderSingh i am not passing values because i need to get all documents in this collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't query for a document that doesn't exist.  Firestore indexes used for querying work based on documents and fields that actually exist - an index can't work with things that don't exist.

If there are subcollections organized under a document ID that doesn't exist, you need to know the path of those subcollections in order to work with them, including the document ID.  There is no way to programmatically discover them if you don't know the document ID where they're organized.