# How to check if a document is empty

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following empty document:

[image]

As I understand it, the document exists, but it's empty.
I'm showing the user a list of all document ID, then allowing him to choose the document to display data for.
When the user chooses this empty document, an error appears because i called length on null object in my listview. That's fair.
I want to show the user an alert dialog informing him that it's empty.

```
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: snapshot,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if(snapshot.data.data.length == 0) {
                      return  AlertDialog(
                        content: Text('Wrong Date', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                        actions: [Icon(Icons.keyboard_backspace)],
                      );
                  }
```

This is what I'm going with at the moment. Just checking the length of the document.
That does not seem right to me.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51556990/6423837 It's java but i believe that the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API for [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), the [data()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) method returns a [Map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Map-class.html) of fields.  If you want to know if there are no fields, simply ask the Map if its [length](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Map/length.html) is 0.

```
snapshot.data().length == 0
```